# How to use MembershipCreateStatus in a class

Tags: c#, class, membership-provider

I'm trying to use the .NET membership provider but I don't know how.

There is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider;

namespace CustomMembership
{
    public class CustomMembership
    {
        public static void CreateUser(String UserName, String Password, String Email, out MembershipCreateStatus  Result)
        {
            SqlConnection Conn= new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=A-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=OyunSitesi;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX");

            Conn.Open();

            SqlCommand CreateUserCommand= new SqlCommand("Inser Into Uyeler (UyeKullaniciAdi,UyeSifre,UyeEposta,UyeGrubu) Values('"+KullaniciAdi+"','"+Sifresi+"','"+EpostaAdresi+"')",Conn);
            CreateUserCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And code continues...

My problem is this code returns `The type or namespace name "MembershipCreateStatus" could not be found (Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: As a sidenote, you're exposing a user id and password to your database which I hope are fake. You're also providing code prone to sql injection.

Comment: I highly suggest you look into an ORM such as LINQ to SQL.

Comment: You have typo in your insert command: should be Insert instead of Inser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this .NET 4.0? System.Web in .NET 4.0 does not seem to have this class definition, have you imported it from an earlier version?
Edit: removed dumbness, sorry.

Comment: .NET 4 certainly _does_ contain this enum. And the `using` for `System.Web.Security` is present in the OPs code. Rather, I think the `System.Web.ApplicationServices` assembly may not be referenced. MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.aspx

Comment: Project is .Net 4.0 I just imported from References > Add Reference > .Net tab and also System.Web.Security is already in the project

Comment: Do you have a reference to `System.Web.ApplicationServices`, too?

Comment: I remember Microsoft changing some stuff around related to MembershipCreateStatus. See here: http://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2010/05/30/Upgrading-to-ASPNET-40-Breaking-change.aspx. Also, here: http://imar.spaanjaars.com/560/using-the-microsoft-access-providers-for-membership-roles-and-profile-under-aspnet-4

Comment: ApplicationServices does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

Comment: @Sefa: You need to reference the assembly using `References > Add Reference > .NET Tab > System.Web.ApplicationServices`, the `using System.Web.Security` is all you need in the code file.

Answer (score 7):

Add reference to the Assembly **System.Web.ApplicationServices**. It should do the trick.